# Select values from an array based on a condition

Tags: php, php-5.6

Say we have the following array:

```
$ar = [2, 5, 3, 1];
```

To select every value that < 4, we can do the following:

```
$newAr = [];
foreach($ar as $val){
    if($val < 4){
        $newAr[] = $val;
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant approach to do this, perhaps with a single function that accepts an array and a predicate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_filter()](http://php.net/array_filter) does the job.

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 5);

function lessThanFour($var) {
    return $var < 4 ? $var : FALSE;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_filter($array1, "lessThanFour"));
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```